# @Transactional and entityManager.persist(o);

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I use Hibernate with JPA. I have a class annotated with @Transactional and within this class I persist some objects:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class ImageRepository {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    public Image factory(String imageHash) {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setHash(imageHash);
        em.persist(image);
        return image;
    }
}
```

I can see that hibernate assigns Id for the image object with `select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')`. But that is all. The object is never put in the database and when I try to run `em.flush();` I am getting:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Also I am not getting any errors.

My application context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${database.structure}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${database.connection}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${database.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${database.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${database.driver}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.writedelay">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

And persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The same happens when I try to merge some objects.

Thanks!

**EDIT 3:**

(previous edits were not relevant)

I noticed, that when I persist or edit object from DWR (DirectWebRemoting) Servlet, I have no problems. When I try to do the same from my own Servlet, I am having mentioned issues. But all the beans of my Servlet are created by Spring by component-scan and with annotations like @Component or @Repository - so I don't see any point, why I should be having such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Transactional` is part of Spring.  It looks like your code isn't using the `Spring context`.

To use the `ImageRepository.factory()` method, it needs to have been **wrapped** by a Spring context for the `@Transactional` annotation to work.

Comment: In the end I found out, that I have <tx:annotation-driven> only in main applicationContext, but not in the servlet-applicationContext. Now it works correctly. Thanks for the hint!